# django with basic Jquery not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a django project which I implemented a jquery function to toggle a link but it is not working. the link does not display the hidden contect i want it to display on toggle. my code is written below.

```
<a href="#" class="comment-reply-btn">REP</a>


<div class="comment-reply" style="display: None;">
        {% for child_comment in comment.children%}

        {{ child_comment.timestamp|timesince }
 {% endfor %}
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comment-reply-btn").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().next("comment-reply").fadeToggle();
    })
  })

  </script>
```

Comment: Paste the final generated HTML from the browser

Comment: generate html content

Comment: That is it. it shows in the browser but it does not work. I checked for typographical  errors or syntax error.

Comment: @Robert kindly check

Comment: @itsneo kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

You're navigating to the wrong DOM element. `next()` finds the next matching sibling, but you've put `parent()` first - so you are looking for the next sibling of that parent. Drop that parent call.

```
$(this).next("comment-reply").fadeToggle();
```

Comment: Help check again please